# Cannot log in as user on OpenBSD

Tags: linux, unix, xorg, login, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD 7.0 installation that has been running for a couple of days. I left it overnight and the computer was off in the morning: apparently there was a power problem. I solved that problem, but when I tried to log in to my regular user account through the graphical environment (I think it's called xenodm), the login screen accepted my credentials, but then simply reappeared: there was no error message about incorrect credentials. I am sure that I did not forget my password: I can log in as root, and I tried changing my password using the `passwd` command. When I tried logging in to my regular user account the same thing happened again. I created a new regular user using the `useradd` command, and I can log in to that new user account, but I still cannot log in to my regular user account. I can also `su` to my regular user account in an Xterm. Of course I could copy all my data from my user's home directory and copy it to a new user directory, but I'm trying to understand what's going on. Does anyone understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I am using the Fish shell as my shell, it's stated in `/etc/passwd`. Since OpenBSD 7.0, Xenodm seems to only login if the shell pointed at by `/etc/passwd` is specified in `/etc/shells`. So I added the full path to Fish in `/etc/shells` and then my user can log in.

Here is my current `/etc/shells`:

```
#       $OpenBSD: shells,v 1.8 2009/02/14 17:06:40 sobrado Exp $
#
# list of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# ftpd(8) will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells, unless the user is listed in /etc/ftpchroot.
/bin/sh
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/usr/local/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/git-shell
/usr/local/bin/fish
```